# Set values using name index in xarray

Tags: python, python-xarray

I'm trying an MA crossover I did in pandas panels using xarray.

Data I'm using:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:          (DATE: 3355, DN_NAME: 22670)
Coordinates:
  * DATE             (DATE) datetime64[ns] 2004-05-18 2004-05-19 2004-05-21 ...
  * DN_NAME          (DN_NAME) object '17836' '1TIME' '4SIGHT' 'A-V-I' ...
Data variables:
    Unnamed: 0       (DATE, DN_NAME) float64 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan ...
    EXCHANGE         (DATE, DN_NAME) object nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan ...
    CODE             (DATE, DN_NAME) object nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan ...
    DNSECTOR         (DATE, DN_NAME) float64 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan ...
    EXCHANGE_SECTOR  (DATE, DN_NAME) object nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan ...
    OPEN             (DATE, DN_NAME) float64 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan ...
    HIGH             (DATE, DN_NAME) float64 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan ...
    LOW              (DATE, DN_NAME) float64 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan ...
    CLOSE            (DATE, DN_NAME) float64 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan ...
    VOLUME           (DATE, DN_NAME) float64 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan ...
    OI               (DATE, DN_NAME) float64 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan ...
    DY               (DATE, DN_NAME) object nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan ...
    EY               (DATE, DN_NAME) float64 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan ...
    VALUE            (DATE, DN_NAME) float64 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan ...
    DEALS            (DATE, DN_NAME) float64 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan ...
    BID              (DATE, DN_NAME) float64 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan ...
    OFFER            (DATE, DN_NAME) float64 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan ...
    CURRENCY         (DATE, DN_NAME) object nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan ...
    ISSUED_SHARES    (DATE, DN_NAME) float64 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan ...
    FULL_NAME        (DATE, DN_NAME) object nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan ...
    MA1              (DATE, DN_NAME) float64 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan ...
    MA2              (DATE, DN_NAME) float64 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan ...
    MA3              (DATE, DN_NAME) float64 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan ...
    MACROSS          int64 0
```

Code that worked with pandas panels:

```
share_data['MACROSS'] = 0
#share_data['MACROSS'][(share_data['MA1'] <= share_data['MA2']) & 
(share_data['MA1'].shift(1) > share_data['MA2'].shift(1))] = -1
```

Now I tried the following in xarray after converting the panel to xarray:

```
ds['MACROSS'] = 0
ds['MACROSS'].sel(MA1 <= ds['MA2'], ds['MA1'].shift(1) > 
ds['MA2'].shift(1)) = 1
```

With the following error, seems I can't use sel indexing to set values:

```
File "<ipython-input-50-af02cd233ed5>", line 17
     ds['MACROSS'].sel(ds['MA1'] > ds['MA2'], ds['MA1'].shift(1) <= 
     ds['MA2'].shift(1)) = 1

^
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

Any idea how to select this subset in xarray and then set the value as intended?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Xarray documentation has a section on [Assigning Values With Indexing](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/indexing.html#assigning-values-with-indexing) and specifically provides this warning:

> Do not try to assign values when using any of the indexing methods isel or sel

Instead, you'll need to use xarray objects to do the indexing. Something like this:

```
date_inds = ...some subset of dates with DATE dimension...
name_inds = ...some subset of names with DN_NAME dimension...

ds['MACROSS'][date_inds, name_inds] = 1
```

Comment: This did not work for me. I get an error stating that my date index cannot be used because it does not have an integer dtype:

```python
invalid indexer array, does not have integer dtype: array(['2014-10-07T00:00:00.000000000', '2014-10-18T00:00:00.000000000',
```

Comment: Note that per the documentation linked above, "Dask array does not support value assignment". And the results were pretty horrific using a local zarr store in xarray 0.21.1, setting a single point in the array *overwrote the entire dataset on disk*. So don't just try this on real data without making sure it'll work for your case first.